# Pagerfanta and Doctrine2 COUNT optimization

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagerfanta

I'm using Pagerfanta and Doctrine Adapters with Symfony2 and Silex. As my database became bigger I noticed huge load on admin stats pages that display big data with pagination. I checked profiler and saw unbelievably inefficient queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id16
FROM (
    SELECT f0_.username AS username0, ..., f0_.added_on AS added_on20
    FROM fos_user f0_ ORDER BY f0_.id DESC
) dctrn_result
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count
FROM (
    SELECT f0_.username AS username0, ..., f0_.added_on AS added_on20
    FROM fos_user f0_ ORDER BY f0_.id DESC
) dctrn_result
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;`
```

First query was easy to fix by creating fixed version of `DoctrineORMAdapter` class. The code that generates `COUNT()` query is more complicated so I decided to ask if there's any solution for this.

So is there any way to make Pagerfanta not running nested queries?

Comment: If you see the code generating an unnecessary complicated query, maybe you should write a bug report at the project's site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Better late than never: I've hit the same wall today with >200k records and found a solution.

Pagerfanta internally uses Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\CountOutputWalker to count objects which results in a count query like this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT id_0 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          m0_.id AS id_0, 
          ...
        FROM 
          messaging_messages m0_ 
        ORDER BY 
          m0_.id DESC
      ) dctrn_result
  ) dctrn_table
```

To bypass CountOutputWalker we can pass a flag when instantiating DoctrineORMAdapter.
So instead of simply

```
$adapter = new DoctrineORMAdapter($qb);
```

you do

```
$adapter = new DoctrineORMAdapter($qb, true, false);
```

(third parameter). This turns the count query into a much more efficient one:

```
SELECT 
  count(DISTINCT m0_.id) AS sclr_0 
FROM 
  messaging_messages m0_
```

You have to update whiteoctober/Pagerfanta to 1.0.3 though.

[Issue](https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta/issues/115)

[Related commit](https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta/commit/d1117846e4d6b53afa3e0bcea4ef1e6af793cff8)

Comment: Note that this will not work if your SELECT query has a HAVING clause

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's not pagerfanta that does the sub-queries. It's the source your query builder instance it's coming from.

I usually have a function in entity repository that returns a plain query builder instance instead of the results. It's left to you to write an efficient query builder. Then I feed that query builder into DoctrineORMAdapter.

I've got this helper function that I use throughout my projects:

```
/**
 * Pass an array, entity or a custom QueryBuilder instance to paginate.
 * Takes an array of parameters as a second argument.
 * Default parameter values:
 *
 * $params = array(
 *     'curPage' => 1,
 *     'perPage' => 15,
 *     'order' => 'DESC'
 * );
 *
 * @param mixed $object
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return Pagerfanta
 */
public function paginate($object, $params = array())
{
    if (is_array($object)) {
        $adapter = new ArrayAdapter($object);
    } elseif ($this->isEntity($object)) {
        $qb      = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('s')
            ->from($this->getEntityName($object), 's')
            ->orderBy('s.id', isset($params['order']) ? $params['order'] : 'DESC');
        $adapter = new DoctrineORMAdapter($qb);
    } elseif ($object instanceof QueryBuilder) {
        $adapter = new DoctrineORMAdapter($object);
    }
    $pager = new Pagerfanta($adapter);
    $pager->setMaxPerPage(isset($params['perPage']) ? $params['perPage'] : 15);
    $pager->setCurrentPage(isset($params['curPage']) ? $params['curPage'] : 1);

    return $pager;
}
```

You can pass an array, entity or a query builder instance and it will return an appropriately paginated object ready to use.

You probably know how it's done, but anyway, here's what I have in my entity repository - one function returns query builder instance (perfect for pagerfanta), the other returns an array to be used elsewhere:

```
public function getMessageQueryBuilder($campaignId, $eqCriteriaArray = array(), $neqCriteriaArray = array())
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
    $qb->select('m')
        ->leftJoin('m.campaign', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('m.sentBy', 'u')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('m.campaign', $campaignId));
    foreach ($eqCriteriaArray as $property => $value) {
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq($property, $qb->expr()->literal($value)));
    }
    foreach ($neqCriteriaArray as $property => $value) {
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->neq($property, $qb->expr()->literal($value)));
    }

    return $qb->orderBy('m.id', 'DESC');
}

public function filterMessages($campaignId, $eqCriteriaArray = array(), $neqCriteriaArray = array())
{
    return $this->getMessageQueryBuilder($campaignId, $eqCriteriaArray, $neqCriteriaArray)->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Then I combine those two to get the actual pager object:

```
$singleSmsPager = $this->pagerUtil->paginate(
    $this->em->getRepository('TreasureForgeMessageBundle:Message')
        ->getMessageQueryBuilder(CcToolSender::CAMPAIGN_ID, array(), array('u.username' => 'admin')),
    array(
        'curPage' => $singleSmsPage,
        'perPage' => 10
    )
);
```

Comment: I don't think so. My queryBuilder (the one I pass to adapter) is only responsible for original select query. The way Pagerfanta creates `COUNT` query from it is different thing.

Comment: Sorry, I've checked my own pagination queries and they seem to do the same type of sub-querying. But then I haven't noticed any relation between performance and the count of records on my application. I would've thought mysql optimiser would limit the inner result set too in such cases. Interesting.

Comment: I've noticed problems when my table reached hundreds of thousands records. It also had high update rate so I think the result couldn't be cached. On other site I have about 2000 items paginated and updated once a day and see no problems